# PHP Laravel class not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am receiving an error when trying to execute $ php artisan passport:install on my terminal, which I will paste below:

```html
In AuthServiceProvider.php line 26:
                                            
  Class 'App\Providers\Passport' not found
```

I suspect the issue is in my config/auth.php , so I will link the contents below (comments removed):

```html
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Below are other files where I have referred to Laravel Passport...

App/user.php :

```html
<?php
    namespace App;
    
    use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
        
        protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'chatkit_id'];
        
        protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
        
        public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
        {
            $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
        }
        }
```

app/providers/AuthServiceProvider.php :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Passport::routes();
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem you need add `Passport`:

```php
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
```

Comment: Awesome, adding that to the top of my app/providers/authserviceprovider.php worked! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you need call to class. `"AuthServiceProvider.php"` add to file top;

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
```

or

```
use App\Providers\Passport;
```

Comment: thoughtfulness. I fixed it.